# How to make author-specific citations with BibTeX?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I'm preparing a document with 100+ references, all sourced from a single `.bib` file. Many -- but not all -- of the references are articles previously written by me and/or some of my current co-authors. We would like these to appear differently in the generated bibliography: preferably using boldface for the citation number, both in the main text and in the (plain-style) bibliography.

Just defining a new command (`\mcite` is what we call it) as `\textbf{\cite[#1]}` works for the in-text part, but of course, doesn't affect the appearance of the bibliography at all.

So far, we've used BibTeX and simple styles, like `plain`. I've looked through the documentation for BibTeX & `biblatex`, as well as `natbib`. Nothing seems to address this; can it be done?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! It would be helpful if you described your document's setup a bit more. E.g., which document class are you using? It appears that you're interested only in numeric-style citations, correct? Please confirm that what you're looking for is that when you create a citation to a piece written by you and/or your co-authors, you want the numeric label(s) to be typeset in bold.

Comment: Hi Mico; thanks for responding.

My documentclass is "article". And yes, I'm only interested in numeric-type citations. When they're to something by me and/or co-authors, they should appear (in text and in the bibliography) as \textbf{[1]}; everything else should appear as plain old [1].

Answer (score 10):

Here a suggestion with `biblatex` in combination with `biber`.

I used the command `\DeclareSourcemap` to find all bib entries from Knuth and add them a `keyword`. This keyword is used for detection in `\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}`:

```
% !TEX program = arara
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: biber
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex
%: Start Header
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[style=numeric,maxnames=6,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\nocite{*}
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=author,
            match=\regexp{Knuth},
            final]
      \step[fieldset=keywords, fieldvalue=knuth]
    }
  }
}
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{%
  \ifkeyword{knuth}{\textbf{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}}
\begin{document}
text
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```