# Make specific author bold using biblatex

Tags: biblatex, bold

I am writing my CV in LaTeX. I am using `biblatex` and want my name (and only my name) to be bold for every reference. Is there a magic way to do this?

A similar question [Make one author's name bold every time it shows up in the bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33330/make-one-authors-name-bold-every-time-it-shows-up-in-the-bibliography) was asked, but that answer used BibTeX. While I use the BibTeX backend, I use `biblatex`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: See: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44200/citing-the-initials-of-one-author-and-the-full-names-of-other-authors/51936#51936 -- Of course this only one suggestion. You can also use `DeclareSourcemap`-- see for example here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62779/how-to-make-author-specific-citations-with-bibtex/65850#65850

Comment: For my own CV, I use `\mkbibbold`. So the author field looks like this: `author={A. Lastname, \mkbibbold{Your name}, A. Lastname}` You should use biber though.

Comment: The solution presented by @rowman wokrs great for me! Thanks!

Comment: I was using the solutions provided here, that worked for biblatex < 3.3, Now none of the solutions provided here works now (biblatex 3.11). The full code of my version is in a different thread: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/187181/independent-publication-list-with-numbered-list-using-biblatex-and-refsection

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Underline my name in the bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18664/underline-my-name-in-the-bibliography) I believe that if you replace "underline" with "bold", that's exactly the same question.

Comment: @Clément Sorry, I voted to reopen this question here. It is *the* go-to collection of answers for `biblatex`. The other question doesn't specifically mention `biblatex`, so not all answers use it and those that do use `biblatex` are by far not as sophisticated as the six answers presented here. If you insist that the should be only one such question, please raise this on meta and ask the mods to merge the answers as well. Just making this a duplicate has the potential to bury lots of good answers behind the duplicate banner.

Comment: @moewe You are right, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You can patch the `name:last`, `name:first-last` and `name:last-first` macros defined in `biblatex.def`. These are used by all of the default name formatting directives and take four arguments:

```
{<last name>}{<first name>}{<name prefix>}{<name affix>}
```

or

```
{<last name>}{<first name (initials)>}{<name prefix>}{<name affix>}
```

In the following we match only on the first and last name parts.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{xpatch}% or use http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/40705

\makeatletter
\newbibmacro*{name:bold}[2]{%
  \edef\blx@tmp@name{\expandonce#1, \expandonce#2}%
  \def\do##1{\ifdefstring{\blx@tmp@name}{##1}{\bfseries\listbreak}{}}%
  \dolistloop{\boldnames}}
\newcommand*{\boldnames}{}
\makeatother

\xpretobibmacro{name:family}{\begingroup\usebibmacro{name:bold}{#1}{#2}}{}{}
\xpretobibmacro{name:given-family}{\begingroup\usebibmacro{name:bold}{#1}{#2}}{}{}
\xpretobibmacro{name:family-given}{\begingroup\usebibmacro{name:bold}{#1}{#2}}{}{}
\xpretobibmacro{name:delim}{\begingroup\normalfont}{}{}

\xapptobibmacro{name:family}{\endgroup}{}{}
\xapptobibmacro{name:given-family}{\endgroup}{}{}
\xapptobibmacro{name:family-given}{\endgroup}{}{}
\xapptobibmacro{name:delim}{\endgroup}{}{}

% just for demonstration
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{maxnames=99,giveninits}
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given/given-family}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\forcsvlist{\listadd\boldnames}
  {{Herrmann, Wolfgang~A.}, {Herrmann, W.~A.}, {Herrmann, Wolfgang\bibnamedelima A.},
   {Herrmann, W\bibinitperiod\bibinitdelim A\bibinitperiod}}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}
\begin{document}
\fullcite{herrmann}

\forcsvlist{\listadd\boldnames}
  {{{\"{O}}fele, Karl}, {{\"{O}}fele, K.}, {{\"{O}}fele, K\bibinitperiod}}
\fullcite{herrmann}

\renewcommand*{\boldnames}{}
\forcsvlist{\listadd\boldnames}
  {{Hoffmann, Stephan~D.}, {Hoffmann, S.~D.}, {Hoffmann, Stephan\bibnamedelima D.},
   {Hoffmann, S\bibinitperiod\bibinitdelim D\bibinitperiod}}
\fullcite{herrmann}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that the name parts in the `\boldnames` `etoolbox` internal list should follow the format of the `bbl` file, which is backend-dependent. The example here covers both biber and BibTeX. With biber you can also perform matching using the `hash` field:

```
\iffieldequalstr{hash}{<hash string>}
```

where `<hash string>` can also be found in the `bbl` file.

If your name is consistently formatted in the `bib` file an alternative approach is to normalize name punctuation before matching. This example allows you to specify your name in BibTeX's format regardless of the backend.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{xpatch}% or use http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/40705

\def\makenamesetup{%
  \def\bibnamedelima{~}%
  \def\bibnamedelimb{ }%
  \def\bibnamedelimc{ }%
  \def\bibnamedelimd{ }%
  \def\bibnamedelimi{ }%
  \def\bibinitperiod{.}%
  \def\bibinitdelim{~}%
  \def\bibinithyphendelim{.-}}    
\newcommand*{\makename}[3]{\begingroup\makenamesetup\xdef#1{#2, #3}\endgroup}

\newbibmacro*{name:bold}[2]{%
  \makename{\currname}{#1}{#2}%
  \makename{\findname}{\lastname}{\firstname}%
  \makename{\findinit}{\lastname}{\firstinit}%
  \ifboolexpr{ test {\ifdefequal{\currname}{\findname}}
            or test {\ifdefequal{\currname}{\findinit}} }{\bfseries}{}}

\newcommand*{\boldname}[3]{%
  \def\lastname{#1}%
  \def\firstname{#2}%
  \def\firstinit{#3}}
\boldname{}{}{}

\xpretobibmacro{name:family}{\begingroup\usebibmacro{name:bold}{#1}{#2}}{}{}
\xpretobibmacro{name:given-family}{\begingroup\usebibmacro{name:bold}{#1}{#2}}{}{}
\xpretobibmacro{name:family-given}{\begingroup\usebibmacro{name:bold}{#1}{#2}}{}{}
\xpretobibmacro{name:delim}{\begingroup\normalfont}{}{}

\xapptobibmacro{name:family}{\endgroup}{}{}
\xapptobibmacro{name:given-family}{\endgroup}{}{}
\xapptobibmacro{name:family-given}{\endgroup}{}{}
\xapptobibmacro{name:delim}{\endgroup}{}{}

% just for demonstration
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{maxnames=99,giveninits}
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given/given-family}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\boldname{Herrmann}{Wolfgang~A.}{W.~A.}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}
\begin{document}
\fullcite{herrmann}

\boldname{{\"O}fele}{Karl}{K.}
\fullcite{herrmann}

\boldname{Hoffmann}{Stephan~D.}{S.~D.}
\fullcite{herrmann}
\end{document}
```

[image]

> This answer was updated to work with versions >= 3.3 of `biblatex`. See the edit history for older versions of `biblatex`. -- moewe

Comment: So this answer looks good (I haven't tried it yet, but I will). But now I have changed to using the `biber` backend. Will this make it easier?

Comment: @Jeremy Not really. You can do pattern matching with biber via `\DeclareSourceMap`, but it's the processed data that really matters - initials, location in the name list, etc. Biber also creates a hash string to identify each name, but its value isn't very meaningful.

Comment: I'm sorry but this totally confuses me, possibly related to the fact that it just doesn't work for me. :( In your example you say that I can do the search via the hash string, but it's not clear where and how. Then in this last comment you state that it's not very meaningful. What do you mean by that? Just that it's abstract, but your suggestion should still be safe?

Comment: @K.-MichaelAye  
Yes, it provides a quick method for identifying a name but the identifier carries no meaning to us. In the above example `\newbibmacro*{name:bold}[2]{\iffieldequalstr{hash}{aa1a2c66bf52b23789b077a79ac3‌​4863}{\bfseries}{}}` would bold the first author's name. I pulled this hash string from the `bbl` file.

Comment: Thanks. BTW, the first method works now. For the hashstring method I found it as well in the `bbl` file, but isn't the loop over the boldnames csvlist obsolete in that case?

Comment: @K.-MichaelAye With hash field matching all you need are the patches - prefix the `name:*` macros with `\begingroup\iffieldequalstr{hash}{aa1a2c66bf52b23789b077a79ac3‌​‌​4863}{\bfseries}{}` and append with `\endgroup`.

Comment: Approach suggested by @Audrey works fine with default reference style or ieee style. I have problems with apa style (biblatex-apa): it won't apply this patch. Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: Shouldn't this answer be updated to reflect the fact that `first` and `last` were deprecated in favor of `given` and `family`, respectively? Making the relevant changes fixes the second MWE in your answer, but even after making those changes, the first MWE no longer works for me.

Comment: I used the second solution for a long time and it used to work beautifully.  Now, however, I had to switch to `style=apa` and it stopped working.  To test it, replace `\usepackage{biblatex}` in the MWE above by `\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes} 
\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}`.  Any suggestions how this can be fixed?  Thank you!

Comment: Update: Both version in this solution stopped working.  I'm running Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 75):

Since `biblatex` 3.4/`biber` 2.5, there is a general "annotation" functionality to do things like this, for example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@MISC{test,
  AUTHOR    = {Last1, First1 and Last2, First2 and Last3, First3},
  AUTHOR+an = {2=highlight},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamegiven}[1]{%
  \ifitemannotation{highlight}
    {\textbf{#1}}
    {#1}}

\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{%
  \ifitemannotation{highlight}
    {\textbf{#1}}
    {#1}}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can also annotate at the name part level and the top-level field level. See the biblatex PDF manual for details.

Comment: "They" is me ... I did indeed. I spent some time on `biber` performance and while `biber` is never going to be as fast as `bibtex` (partly because it does a lot more than `bibtex` in the `biblatex` use case), it currently shows, in version 2.5, 400% speed improvement in the large test cases I used for tuning compared with any previous versions.

Comment: This look really neat.  Is there a way to use this to highlight a name without hard-coding that in the bibliography.  I'd like to highlight my name in my CV but not in articles.  Thank you!

Comment: @tmalsburg - Well, you have to have some marker in the bibliography but without the annotation commands, they won't do anything so you can easily control whether anything is highlighted.

Comment: Great solution, thank you! I'm just wondering is it possible to use this only in the bibliography and not in the text? Currently citations also show text as bold

Comment: Yes, just wrap the `\renewcommand` macros in `\AtEveryBibitem` so that they only apply to bibliography items.

Comment: In case anybody wants to highlight multiple authors, you can do so this way: `AUTHOR+an = {1=highlight;2=highlight},`

Answer (score 40):

As I couldn't use https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/73246/7561 as well, and in case others stumble into this looking for a solution, I'm updating the answers. As pointed by Adam Liter, in the comments of that answer, the options used in the previous answer are deprecated and doesn't work (at least for me).

### Solution

Instead, I redefined the `\mkbibnamegiven` and `\mkbibnamefamily`, and used the same ideas as before.

Basically, you use the `\boldname` to the define the name you want to mark as bold, like: `\boldname{Lastname}{Givenname}{G.}`.

```
\newcommand*{\boldname}[3]{%
  \def\lastname{#1}%
  \def\firstname{#2}%
  \def\firstinit{#3}}
\boldname{}{}{}
```

Then, we redefine the macros that generate the given and family names. The main idea is to search for the named defined above, and if it is found (including the given and family name) it makes it bold (using `\mkbibbold`), if not it leaves it as is.

```
% Patch new definitions
\renewcommand{\mkbibnamegiven}[1]{%
  \ifboolexpr{ ( test {\ifdefequal{\firstname}{\namepartgiven}} or test {\ifdefequal{\firstinit}{\namepartgiven}} ) and test {\ifdefequal{\lastname}{\namepartfamily}} }
  {\mkbibbold{#1}}{#1}%
}

\renewcommand{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{%
  \ifboolexpr{ ( test {\ifdefequal{\firstname}{\namepartgiven}} or test {\ifdefequal{\firstinit}{\namepartgiven}} ) and test {\ifdefequal{\lastname}{\namepartfamily}} }
  {\mkbibbold{#1}}{#1}%
}
```

### Example

A full example:

```
% !BIB program = biber
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,maxbibnames=99,defernumbers=true,sorting=ydnt,giveninits=true]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@InProceedings{identifier1,
  Title                    = {Some Awesome Title},
  Author                   = {Some Author and Another Author},
  Booktitle                = {Some Book about the Future},
  Year                     = {2042},
  Pages                    = {1--42}
}

@InProceedings{identifier2,
  Title                    = {Some So-So Title},
  Author                   = {First Author and Second Author},
  Booktitle                = {An okay Booktitle},
  Year                     = {2000},
  Pages                    = {1--100}
}

  @Book{test1,
  author          = {Goossens, Michel and Mittelbach, Frank
    and Samarin, Alexander},
  title           = {The LaTeX Companion},
  publisher       = {Addison-Wesley},
  location        = {Reading, Mass.},
  year            = {1994},

}

@Book{test2,
  author          = {Mittelbach, F. and Goossens, Michel
    and Samarin, Alexander},
  title           = {The LaTeX Companion},
  publisher       = {Addison-Wesley},
  location        = {Reading, Mass.},
  year            = {1994},

}

@Book{test3,
  author          = {Mittelbach, Frank and Samarin, Alexander
    and Goossens, Michel},
  title           = {The LaTeX Companion},
  publisher       = {Addison-Wesley},
  location        = {Reading, Mass.},
  year            = {1994},
} 
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\def\makenamesetup{%
  \def\bibnamedelima{~}%
  \def\bibnamedelimb{ }%
  \def\bibnamedelimc{ }%
  \def\bibnamedelimd{ }%
  \def\bibnamedelimi{ }%
  \def\bibinitperiod{.}%
  \def\bibinitdelim{~}%
  \def\bibinithyphendelim{.-}}    
\newcommand*{\makename}[2]{\begingroup\makenamesetup\xdef#1{#2}\endgroup}

\newcommand*{\boldname}[3]{%
  \def\lastname{#1}%
  \def\firstname{#2}%
  \def\firstinit{#3}}
\boldname{}{}{}

% Patch new definitions
\renewcommand{\mkbibnamegiven}[1]{%
  \ifboolexpr{ ( test {\ifdefequal{\firstname}{\namepartgiven}} or test {\ifdefequal{\firstinit}{\namepartgiven}} ) and test {\ifdefequal{\lastname}{\namepartfamily}} }
  {\mkbibbold{#1}}{#1}%
}

\renewcommand{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{%
  \ifboolexpr{ ( test {\ifdefequal{\firstname}{\namepartgiven}} or test {\ifdefequal{\firstinit}{\namepartgiven}} ) and test {\ifdefequal{\lastname}{\namepartfamily}} }
  {\mkbibbold{#1}}{#1}%
}

\boldname{Author}{Some}{S.}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\boldname{Goossens}{Michel}{M.}
\printbibliography

\boldname{Mittelbach}{Frank}{F.}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image: showcase]

### Update

Added support for checking given and family names before bolding the name.

Comment: Among solutions I found, only this one works for me (MikTex on Windows). Thanks.

Comment: I cannot get this to work with middle names the way the Audrey answer used to, eg. if the author were "Frank Allen Mittelbach." Any thoughts?

Comment: If you are using adn's solution for the moderncv class you need to change the \firstname \lastname commands to make it work (since they are in conflict with the classes commands)

Comment: @Ohjeah could you provide a solution regarding to using this with moderncv?

Comment: This solution almost works for me @adn, however it doesn't recognize more complex names, for instance `\boldname{van Gut Goossens}{Michel}{M.}` or when the name comes in multiple forms as in the short version of your example and this long version. One solution I tried, and could would work for some purposes would be to highlight just at last word in the name, `\boldname{Goossens}{}{}`, but that doesn't highlight anything at all. Any ideas for a workaround? Cheers.

Answer (score 17):

This is more or less a copy of my answer to [Highlight an author in bibliography using biblatex allowing bibliography style to format it](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/274436/35864).

The following implements [Audrey's solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/73246/35864) for name hashes. The advantage of using hashes is that you only have to give one version of the name, all normalisation will be performed by Biber. The great disadvantage of hashes is that they are not easy to handle for humans. `biblatex` can't create the hashes on the fly, so that they need to be looked up in the `.bbl` file.  The following solution automates hash lookup from the `.bbl`, so that you can use it more easily.

The solution works by writing all names you want in bold to dummy entries in a separate `.bib` file called `\jobname -boldnames.bib` (*Warning* That file will be overwritten without warning. In the unlikely event you already have a file of that name, you can rename the file by changing the command `\hlblx@bibfile@name`.). Biber then calculates the name hashes for us. These hashes can then be extracted using a dummy cite command (`\nhblx@getmethehash`) and are added to a list of names, which we can test against. All of this is hidden in higher-level macros and happens automatically, so you don't have to worry about the details.

Usage is very simple. Use `\addboldnames` to add a list of names to be highlighted. `\addboldnames` accepts a comma-separated list of names in the same format as you would write them to the `.bib` file. If a name contains a comma, the entire name must be wrapped in curly braces.

```
\addboldnames{{Silva, Carlos F. M.},{Silva, Jr., José Mairton B.}}
```

or

```
\addboldnames{Emma Sigfridsson}
```

`\addboldnames` can be used in the preamble and the document body.

To reset the list of names to be highlighted, use `\resetboldnames`.

In the name formatting directives we can now use `\mkboldifhashinlist` to check if the current name is in the list of names for bolding.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric]{biblatex}

\makeatletter
\def\nhblx@bibfile@name{\jobname -nhblx.bib}
\newwrite\nhblx@bibfile
\immediate\openout\nhblx@bibfile=\nhblx@bibfile@name

\immediate\write\nhblx@bibfile{%
  @comment{Auto-generated file}\blx@nl}

\newcounter{nhblx@name}
\setcounter{nhblx@name}{0}

\newcommand*{\nhblx@writenametobib}[1]{%
  \stepcounter{nhblx@name}%
  \edef\nhblx@tmp@nocite{%
    \noexpand\AfterPreamble{%
      \noexpand\setbox0\noexpand\vbox{%
        \noexpand\nhblx@getmethehash{nhblx@name@\the\value{nhblx@name}}}}%
  }%
  \nhblx@tmp@nocite
  \immediate\write\nhblx@bibfile{%
    @misc{nhblx@name@\the\value{nhblx@name}, author = {\unexpanded{#1}}, %
          options = {dataonly=true},}%
  }%
}

\AtEndDocument{%
  \closeout\nhblx@bibfile}

\addbibresource{\nhblx@bibfile@name}

\newcommand*{\nhblx@boldhashes}{}
\DeclareNameFormat{nhblx@hashextract}{%
  \xifinlist{\thefield{hash}}{\nhblx@boldhashes}
    {}
    {\listxadd{\nhblx@boldhashes}{\thefield{hash}}}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\nhblx@getmethehash}
  {}
  {\printnames[nhblx@hashextract][1-999]{author}}
  {}
  {}

\newcommand*{\addboldnames}{\forcsvlist\nhblx@writenametobib}
\newcommand*{\resetboldnames}{\def\nhblx@boldhashes{}}

\newcommand*{\ifhashinboldlist}{%
  \xifinlist{\thefield{hash}}{\nhblx@boldhashes}}
\makeatother

\newcommand*{\mkboldifhashinlist}[1]{%
  \ifhashinboldlist
    {\mkbibbold{#1}}
    {#1}}

\DeclareNameWrapperFormat{boldifhashinlist}{%
  \renewcommand*{\mkbibcompletename}{\mkboldifhashinlist}%
  #1}

\DeclareNameWrapperAlias{sortname}{default}
\DeclareNameWrapperAlias{default}{boldifhashinlist}

\addboldnames{{Sigfridsson, Emma},{Vizedom, Monika B.}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\fullcite{sigfridsson}

\fullcite{knuth:ct:a}

\fullcite{vizedom:related}

\resetboldnames\addboldnames{Donald E. Knuth}
\fullcite{knuth:ct:a}

\resetboldnames\addboldnames{Philipp Jaff{\'e}}
\fullcite{jaffe}
\end{document}
```

[image: Bibliography with several names highlighted in bold.]

*edited* to use a more elegant version to format complete names. `\DeclareNameWrapperFormat` and `\mkbibcompletename` are only available in `biblatex` v3.12 (2018-10-30) and v3.13 (2019-08-17), respectively. Please refer to the edit history if you are using an older version of `biblatex`.

Comment: What about name variants such as D. E. Knuth and Donald E. Knuth?

Comment: @jlconlin Of course that does not work. As far as Biber/`biblatex` are concerned these two are different people. How would they know differently?

Answer (score 5):

There is still an issue with the last answer by adn: The sub macros that use the Strings in `\boldname{Goossens}{Michel}{M.}` only search for these strings (i.e., "Goossens", "Michel", and "M.") independently of each other. That is: *any* occurrence of "M." will be bold, no matter whether it belongs to a different author (like "M." for "Martin"). Improving the search scripts to only make the respective names bold if they are detected in a sequence would solve this behavior. In its current form, its usefulness is quite limited given there are more than just a couple of references.

Here a MWE that shows the problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,maxbibnames=99,defernumbers=true,sorting=ydnt,giveninits=true]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@InProceedings{identifier1,
  Title                    = {Some Awesome Title},
  Author                   = {Some Author and Another Author},
  Booktitle                = {Some Book about the Future},
  Year                     = {2042},
  Pages                    = {1--42}
}

@InProceedings{identifier2,
  Title                    = {Some So-So Title},
  Author                   = {First Author and Second Author},
  Booktitle                = {An okay Booktitle},
  Year                     = {2000},
  Pages                    = {1--100}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\def\makenamesetup{%
  \def\bibnamedelima{~}%
  \def\bibnamedelimb{ }%
  \def\bibnamedelimc{ }%
  \def\bibnamedelimd{ }%
  \def\bibnamedelimi{ }%
  \def\bibinitperiod{.}%
  \def\bibinitdelim{~}%
  \def\bibinithyphendelim{.-}}    
\newcommand*{\makename}[2]{\begingroup\makenamesetup\xdef#1{#2}\endgroup}

\newcommand*{\boldname}[3]{%
  \def\lastname{#1}%
  \def\firstname{#2}%
  \def\firstinit{#3}}
\boldname{}{}{}

% Patch new definitions
\renewcommand{\mkbibnamegiven}[1]{%
  \makename{\currname}{#1}%
  \makename{\findname}{\firstname}%
  \makename{\findinit}{\firstinit}%
  \ifboolexpr{ test {\ifdefequal{\currname}{\findname}}%
    or test {\ifdefequal{\currname}{\findinit}} }%
  {\mkbibbold{#1}}{#1}%
}

\renewcommand{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{%
  \makename{\currname}{#1}%
  \makename{\findname}{\lastname}%
  \ifboolexpr{ test {\ifdefequal{\currname}{\findname}} }%
  {\mkbibbold{#1}}{#1}%
}

\boldname{Author}{Some}{S.}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

It produces the following PDF, in which:

(a) all occurrences of "S." are bold, although one stands for "Second", which does not belong to the name "Some Author" and

(b) all occurrences of "Author" are bold (i.e., all four authors!), although just one matches the desired author "Some Author"

[image: wrongly matched names, as described above]

I hence propose another solution, which does solve this problem (however, there are other problems with it - and I would be glad if someone would present a solution for it). The solution was mentioned in [Make one author's name bold every time it shows up in the bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33330/make-one-authors-name-bold-every-time-it-shows-up-in-the-bibliography) (this link is also given in the very first post here one that page). However, (a) it *does* work with `biblatex`, although jlconlin says that it only works with `bibtex` and (b) I have extended it a bit to provide some further functionalities that you would not get without it (but that are provided by the previous answer, given by adn).

That solution simply uses a macro in the `bibtex` files instead of the actual authors' names. Then, the `\textbf{}` macro does work, while the document would not compile if `\textbf{}` would be inserted directly in the .bib file.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber,maxbibnames=99,defernumbers=true,sorting=ydnt,giveninits=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@InProceedings{identifier1,
  Title                    = {Some Awesome Title},
  Author                   = {\MyName[someKey]{S. Author} and Another Author},
  Booktitle                = {Some Book about the Future},
  Year                     = {2042},
  Pages                    = {1--42}
}

@InProceedings{identifier2,
  Title                    = {Some So-So Title},
  Author                   = {First Author and Second Author},
  Booktitle                = {An okay Booktitle},
  Year                     = {2000},
  Pages                    = {1--100}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\MyName}[2][\empty]{  % \empty is default for the opt. argument
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{\empty}} % test the opt. argument
    {\hspace*{-.75mm}#2}          % it's empty! just show mand. argument   
    {\hspace*{-.75mm}\textbf{#2}} % it's not empty! make mand. argument (the name) bold
}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

It produces the following PDF:
[image]

As can be seen: the problem is solved, as *exactly* those authors are shown bold that use the macro. To be more precise: the is now an optional argument, which can be instantiated by any String of the user's choice. This "key" can be used in the definition of `\MyName` to define more specific behavior. For instance, I use `biblatex` to use keywords (given in an extra keywords fields - not given here) in order to give several reference sections, divided by the keywords. If making an author's name bold should depend on that keyword (which is the case for me), that logic can be put into the if-then statement. (In my example, the name in the `\MyName` macro is shown bold if there is *any* keyword given and non-bold, otherwise. This can be extended -- obviously -- to match any specific key.

It is important to know that this solution does not support to abbreviate the authors' names given in the macro. You will see that I passed "S. Author" to `\MyName` instead of "Some Author", because latex/bibtex cannot produce "S. Author" from it. However, this does not make this solution any less practical, I think.

Its problem: *All* names which are put into the `\MyName` macro appear more to the right than without using the macro. That is, there is a space of approx. 2mm on the left of any such name. This occurs independently of the matching if case, i.e., no matter whether it is bold or not. This is the reason why I have added a negative `\hspace` in front of it. However,

(a) this quiet dirty. Isn't there a (la)tex macro that eliminates the additional space? and

(b) it is impossible to find the correct space that needs to be subtracted, because it is different for different `bibtex` entries (sometimes this automatically inserted space is larger, sometimes it is smaller)

Comment: Check the updated answer. Your approach is also a solution. But I wanted something that does not involve updating the bib files.

Comment: How can I have the same thing but with underline instead of bold?

Answer (score 2):

Combining solution by adn, and suggestion by Audrey to use the "hash" field generated by biber, this works (texlive 2017.20170818-1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,maxbibnames=99,defernumbers=true,sorting=ydnt,giveninits=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

% Run biber once, find the hash you want in the generated .bbl file 
% (here, M. Goossens) and paste here:
\edef\authorhash{\detokenize{0743efb276e9219ee664a9b3dbd60619}}

\renewcommand{\mkbibnamegiven}[1]{%
  \iffieldequals{hash}{\authorhash}{\mkbibbold{#1}}{#1}}
\renewcommand{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{%
  \iffieldequals{hash}{\authorhash}{\mkbibbold{#1}}{#1}}
\renewcommand{\mkbibnameprefix}[1]{%
  \iffieldequals{hash}{\authorhash}{\mkbibbold{#1}}{#1}}
\renewcommand{\mkbibnamesuffix}[1]{%
  \iffieldequals{hash}{\authorhash}{\mkbibbold{#1}}{#1}}

\begin{document}
\nocite{companion}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

**Edit:** Following moewe's good advices, fixes and verifications (thanks !) :

- switched to using the distrib’s .bib sample
- added support to prefix/suffix parts of the  names
- used a macro to avoid copy-pasting hash 4 times

Patching `name:` as suggested by Audrey would indeed be more efficient but apparently it does not work anymore for some reason (see comment [Make specific author bold using biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73136/make-specific-author-bold-using-biblatex/414334#comment832191_73246)).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You could make your answer more useful if you used `biblatex-examples`, a file that is automatically available if `biblatex` is installed, instead of `mybiblio.bib`, which we don't have. You can avoid having to paste the hash twice if you save it in a macro. Note also that if the name has a suffix or prefix that will not be printed in bold with your solution.

Comment: `\edef\boldname{\detokenize{0743efb276e9219ee664a9b3dbd60619}}

\renewcommand{\mkbibnamegiven}[1]{%
  \iffieldequals{hash}{\boldname}{\mkbibbold{#1}}{#1}%
}
\renewcommand{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{%
  \iffieldequals{hash}{\boldname}{\mkbibbold{#1}}{#1}%
}` (modulo line breaks) works for me. The hashes are detokenized so we need to do the same. `\mkbibnamesuffix` and `\mkbibnameprefix` should work, not sure how you added the fields by hand. The great advantage of Audrey's patching the `name:` macros instead of `\mkbibname...` is that the entire name is processed in one go ...

Comment: ... and not each name part separately.

Comment: Patching `name:` does still work, but you have to replace `last` by `family` and `first` by `given`. There were some change in name handling in version 3.3, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/299036/35864

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/274436/35864 for a full solution with `hashes` that works.

Comment: OK, thanks again. I'll leave it like it is, then : this may be a handy intermediate solution in case something breaks again.

Answer (score 1):

Another easy solution is to use the [publist package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-publist)

It doesn't require to modify the bib file (like in [PLK answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/304968/35864)) especially useful if the file is generated automatically. It also works correctly with more complex family name (with two words for example) as opposed to [Audrey's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/73246/243449).
The package adds also some other nice features for generating publication list.

Syntax it pretty straightforward and concise:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[%
  bibstyle=publist,
  backend=biber,
  defernumbers=true,
  sorting=ydnt,
  natbib=true,
  maxbibnames=99,
  giveninits=true,
  isbn=false,doi=false,url=false,eprint=false, %
  plauthorhandling=highlight,boldyear=false %
]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@InProceedings{identifier1,
  Title                    = {Some Awesome Title},
  Author                   = {My Family Name, MyForname and Author, Another},
  Booktitle                = {Some Book about the Future},
  Year                     = {2042},
  Pages                    = {1--43}
}

@InProceedings{identifier2,
  Title                    = {Some So-So Title},
  Author                   = {Author, Another and My Family Name, M.},
  Booktitle                = {An okay Booktitle},
  Year                     = {2000},
  Pages                    = {1--100}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}
\plauthorname[MyForname][]{My Family Name}
\plauthorname[M.][]{My Family Name}
\nocite{*}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The result:
[image]

Comment: PLK's answer (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/304968/35864) will work fine with more complex family names since it uses data annotation which is decoupled from the actual name. My answer (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/416416/35864) also works fine (https://gist.github.com/moewew/291c65df0d6db091bd1c29322765f2f0), because it uses name hashes. Some of the simpler answers using string comparison may indeed have issues with the `\bibnamedelima` added by the backend.

Comment: Some of the other solutions have quite some code to normalise stuff like `\bibnamedelima`, so they should work as well provided you find the right input for the macros.

Comment: I certainly haven't properly tested all answers. I've edited the answer

Answer (score 1):

I had the most annoying variation on this problem:

- I had to highlight multiple authors, not just one
- I had family name clashes, meaning I had to match on more than just the family name
- I had the additional requirement that certain authors should only be highlighted in publications after a certain date.

I eventually figured out how to satisfy all of these and end up with pretty compact code. I loop over a list of authors to highlight and match on both the family name and the first initial of the given name, also checking the biblatex data for the year.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{xstring} % Used for string matching

\newcommand{\mkmatchformat}{}%
\newcommand{\matchbold}{%
    \renewcommand{\mkmatchformat}{}%
    \renewcommand\do[1]{%
        \StrCut{##1}{.}\csinit\cstmp
        \StrCut{\cstmp}{,}\csfam\csyear
        \ifboolexpr{%
            test {\IfBeginWith{\namepartgiven}{\csinit}}%
            and test {\IfSubStr{\namepartfamily}{\csfam}}%
            and test {\ifnumcomp{\thefield{year} + 1}{>}{\csyear}}%
        }{%
            \renewcommand{\mkmatchformat}{\mkbibbold}%
            \listbreak%
        }{}%
    }%
    \dolistloop{\mylab}%
    \mkmatchformat{\printname}%
}

\newcommand{\printname}{}
\renewcommand{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{%
    \renewcommand\printname{#1}%
    \matchbold{}%
}
\renewcommand{\mkbibnamegiven}[1]{%
    \renewcommand\printname{#1}%
    \matchbold{}
}

% Test data.
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

% List names to match using the first initial of given name, family name,
% and earliest year pubilcation for which name should be highlighted.
% Format {I.Familyname,year}.
\newcommand*{\mylab}{}
\listadd{\mylab}{D.Knuth,1986}
\listadd{\mylab}{S.Kullback,1990}
\listadd{\mylab}{W.Herrmann,2000}
\listadd{\mylab}{S.Hoffmann,2000}
\listadd{\mylab}{S.Schneider,2008}

% Bibformat so we can see all the names.
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{maxnames=99,giveninits}


\begin{document}

\fullcite{knuth:ct:b}

\fullcite{knuth:ct:c}

\fullcite{knuth:ct:a}

\fullcite{kullback}

\fullcite{kullback:related}

\fullcite{herrmann}

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

Answer (score 1):

As of `biblatex` 3.13 (released 2019-08-17), there is the `\mkbibcompletename` command.

In the preamble:

```latex
\renewcommand*{\mkbibcompletename}[1]{%
  \ifitemannotation{highlight}
    {\textbf{#1}}%                e.g., ,   (if highlight)
    {#1}%                         e.g., Yoda, Master   (otherwise)
}
```

Now to annotate authors "2" and "4" as `highlight` authors:

```
@inproceedings{skywalker4096history,
  author    = {Skywalker, Anakin and Yoda, Master and Kenobi, Obi-Wan and Windu, Mace},
  author+an = {2=highlight;4=highlight},
  title     = {The History of Jedi Knights},
  date      = {4096},
  booktitle = {Proceedings of the Jedi Council},
}
```

Output:

[image: A. Skywalker, M. Yoda, O.-W. Kenobi, and M. Windu, “The history of jedi knights,” in Proceedings of the Jedi Council, 4096.]