# Make specific author bold using biblatex without consistent author formatting

Tags: biblatex, bold

A while back I asked this question:

[Make specific author bold using biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73136/make-specific-author-bold-using-biblatex)

Essentially, I want to **highlight** my name in the publications portion of my CV. I got a good answer from my previous question which included this line:

```
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{maxnames=99,firstinits}
```

which converts all the author names to first initials plus a last name.

There was one caveat that is now coming to bite me:

> If your name is consistently formatted in the `bib` file...

My name is not consistently formatted in the `bib` file. Sometimes it is `Jeremy Lloyd Conlin` other times it is `J. L. Conlin` and still `J. Conlin`.

I want to bold all of my names while keeping the original name, i.e., I don't want the author names reduced to first initials and last names. Is this possible?

Comment: Interesting. I don't include my name in my list of publications at all in my CV. (For this reason, I don't use biblatex as I can't format the entries correctly for a CV.) Why do you want names formatted inconsistently in any list of references?

Comment: @cfr I prefer to use my full name whenever possible so I don't like it when `biblatex` changes everything to initials. Unfortunately that means my name is used inconsistently depending on the preference of the first author.

Comment: Then don’t `biblatex` do that and keep your `.bib` verbose as well.

Comment: The caveat applies to only the second approach given. To solve your problem see the first approach or use biber's source map feature to normalize your name.

Comment: @Audrey That caveat appears to apply only to the second approach. However, I was (am) using the first approach and still only get first initials.

Comment: @Jeremy Then don't enable `firstinits`. It is enabled in the examples just for demonstration.

Comment: @Audrey I tried that, but then my name isn't **highlighted**.

Comment: @Jeremy `firstinits` doesn't change the data, just how it is displayed. In the `\boldnames` list you must specify all the ways your last and first names appear in the `bbl` file. Under biber this could be `\boldnames{{Conlin, Jeremy\bibnamedelima Lloyd}, {Conlin, J.\bibnamedelimi L.}, {Conlin, J.}}`, but you'll have to check the `bbl` file. All of this was covered in the original post. I don't think your issue warrants a new question, but feel free to post an answer.

Comment: @Audrey I tried doing that, but couldn't get any of my names to be **highlighted**. Of course there are any number of combinations that are possible; I may not have found all of them.

Comment: @Jeremy Sorry - I had a typo. Should be `\forcsvlist{\listadd\boldnames}{...}` following the first example. Each item in the name list should be in the format `{<last name>, <first name>}`, where `<first name>` should be the full name only.

Comment: @Audrey I was able to get all my names **highlighted**. I looked in the `bbl` file as you suggested and found the possible combinations. It took me awhile to figure out what they need to be, but I got it done. Thanks for your help. Now how can I choose an answer to this question?

Comment: @Audrey could you help me out with http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/187994/multiple-names-bold-in-bibliography  I'm using your example, but some of my names only have last name.