# Automatically emphasize \author names in bibliography and citations

Tags: biblatex, biber, automation

This is a follow-up question to [Make specific author bold using biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/73246/41085).

Using `biblatex` and `biber` and either XeLaTeX or LuaTeX, would it be possible to extract all names from the `\author` command, which is mainly used for `\maketitle`, and automatically highlight (or “lowlight”) them in citations and bibliographies?

Basically this is “just” asking how to extract names from `\author` (multiple ones split by `and`), parse for first/given names and last/family name and finally put these in the `\boldname` macro from the aforementioned answer.

```
%% \boldname{family name}{given name}{initials}
\newcommand*{\boldname}[3]{%
  \def\lastname{#1}%
  \def\firstname{#2}%
  \def\firstinit{#3}}

\boldname{}{}{}
```

Comment: Can't you replace \author by another command which puts the real \author with a pre-defined variable, which will be set beforehand? Then you will have a variable with your desired author...

Comment: You should look at `titling` which lets you continue to use the values of assigned in `\author` etc. after `\maketitle`.

Comment: @cfr: `titling` helps, but is not yet a solution, because I would still have to split up its `\theauthor` into first and last name at least. Does `biblatex` do this by itself – which could be copied easily – or is that the responsibility of the backend (`biber`/BibTeX)?

Comment: @ido: You mean like `\newcommand*\authorname[3][]{\author{#2 #3} \boldname{#3}{#2}{#1}}` where `#1` is the optional initials, `#2` the given name and `#3` the family name? That should work, indeed, but only for a single author.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building upon @ido’s suggestion, this should (almost) work, but requires a different workflow, which is something I wanted to avoid actually.

```
\newcommand*\authors{}
\newcommand*\addauthor[1]{%
  \let\oldauthors\authors
  \renewcommand*\authors{%
    \ifempty{\oldauthors}{}{\oldauthors{} and }#1%
  }
}
\newcommand*\authorname[3][]{%
  \addauthor{#2 #3}
  \boldname{#3}{#2}{#1}
}

\authorname[J.]{John}{Doe}
\authorname[J.]{Jane}{Doe}

\author{\authors}
```