# Emphasize author in bibliography for use in CV

Tags: bibliographies, emphasis

I would like to create a bibliography for my CV, where my name is emphasized to stand out from the list of authors. I've already tried various things, including the suggestions provided [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/160241/automatically-emphasize-author-names-in-bibliography-and-citations) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91257/underline-different-authors-in-the-bibliography-by-hacking-bst-file). However, nothing seems to work with the particular style I would like to follow. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

This is my .tex file. It contains two attempts that worked at least partially. the `\newcommand{\bibnamefont}` gives something close to what I want, but this way I can only emphasize "Boll" or "R." or both, but not "R. Boll" exclusively.

The solution `%\let\originalbibitem`... does that, but it only works when I use the `\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}` instead of my .bst file, where it results in `! File ended while scanning use of \bibitem.` I am guessing that my `\bibitem` follows a different logic compared to what is used in the example, but I'm not sure how I could change it for my case.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}  
\RequirePackage{color,graphicx}  
\usepackage         [super, compress]       {natbib}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[top=0.9in, bottom=0.9in, left=0.9in, right=0.9in]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\definecolor{darkblue}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.5}
\hypersetup{colorlinks = true, urlcolor=darkblue, citecolor=white}
\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand{\bibnamefont}[1]{\IfSubStr{#1}{Boll} {{\color{darkblue} \textbf{#1}}}{#1}} 
\newcommand{\bibfnamefont}[1]{\IfStrEq{#1}{R.} {{\color{darkblue}\textbf{#1}}}{#1}} 

%\renewcommand{\bibfield}[1]{\IfSubStr{#1}{Boll} {\StrSubstitute{#1}{\bibnamefont {Boll}}{\color{darkblue}\textbf{Boll}}}{#1}} 

%\let\originalbibitem\bibitem
%\def\bibitem#1#2\par{%
%\noexpandarg \originalbibitem{#1}
%\StrSubstitute{#2}{R.~Boll}{{\color{darkblue}\textbf{R.~Boll}}} \par}

\begin{document}

\bibliographystyle{all_authors_with_title}
%\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}

\bibliography{bib}

{\color{white}
\cite{boll_imaging_2014}

\end{document}
```

This is the content of the bib file:

```
@article{boll_imaging_2014,
title = {Imaging molecular structure through femtosecond photoelectron diffraction on aligned and oriented gas-phase molecules},
volume = {171},
issn = {1359-6640, 1364-5498},
url = {http://xlink.rsc.org/?DOI=C4FD00037D},
doi = {10.1039/C4FD00037D},
urldate = {2015-02-09},
journal = {Faraday Discussions},
author = {Boll, Rebecca and Rouz{\'e}e, Arnaud and Adolph, Marcus and Anielski, Denis and Aquila, Andrew and Bari, Sadia and Bomme, C{\'e}dric and Bostedt, Christoph and Bozek, John D. and Chapman, Henry N. and Christensen, Lauge and Coffee, Ryan and Coppola, Niccola and De, Sankar and Decleva, Piero and Epp, Sascha W. and Erk, Benjamin and Filsinger, Frank and Foucar, Lutz and Gorkhover, Tais and Gumprecht, Lars and H{\"o}mke, Andr{\'e} and Holmegaard, Lotte and Johnsson, Per and Kienitz, Jens S. and Kierspel, Thomas and Krasniqi, Faton and K{\"u}hnel, Kai-Uwe and Maurer, Jochen and Messerschmidt, Marc and Moshammer, Robert and M{\"u}ller, Nele L. M. and Rudek, Benedikt and Savelyev, Evgeny and Schlichting, Ilme and Schmidt, Carlo and Scholz, Frank and Schorb, Sebastian and Schulz, Joachim and Seltmann, J{\"o}rn and Stener, Mauro and Stern, Stephan and Techert, Simone and Th{\o}gersen, Jan and Trippel, Sebastian and Viefhaus, Jens and Vrakking, Marc and Stapelfeldt, Henrik and K{\"u}pper, Jochen and Ullrich, Joachim and Rudenko, Artem and Rolles, Daniel},
month = jul,
year = {2014},
pages = {57--80},
file = {Boll et al. - 2014 - Imaging molecular structure through femtosecond ph.pdf:D\:\\Cloud\\zotero\\storage\\557IX9NU\\Boll et al. - 2014 - Imaging molecular structure through femtosecond ph.pdf:application/pdf}
}
```

I would like to attach the .bst file as well, but I can't figure out how to add a file to the post. It is too long to post as code. I am using a modified version of the apsrev4-1.bst. Instead, I attach here the .bbl file, maybe it also helps.

I'm new to this page, so I apologize in case I didn't obey some formatting rules.

```
%merlin.mbs apsrev4-1.bst 2010-07-25 4.21a (PWD, AO, DPC) hacked
%Control: key (0)
%Control: author (5) initials jnrlst
%Control: editor formatted (1) identically to author
%Control: production of article title (1) required
%Control: page (0) single
%Control: year (1) truncated
%Control: production of eprint (0) enabled
\begin{thebibliography}{1}%
\makeatletter
\providecommand \@ifxundefined [1]{%
 \@ifx{#1\undefined}
}%
\providecommand \@ifnum [1]{%
 \ifnum #1\expandafter \@firstoftwo
 \else \expandafter \@secondoftwo
 \fi
}%
\providecommand \@ifx [1]{%
 \ifx #1\expandafter \@firstoftwo
 \else \expandafter \@secondoftwo
 \fi
}%
\providecommand \natexlab [1]{#1}%
\providecommand \enquote  [1]{``#1''}%
\providecommand \bibnamefont  [1]{#1}%
\providecommand \bibfnamefont [1]{#1}%
\providecommand \citenamefont [1]{#1}%
\providecommand \href@noop [0]{\@secondoftwo}%
\providecommand \href [0]{\begingroup \@sanitize@url \@href}%
\providecommand \@href[1]{\@@startlink{#1}\@@href}%
\providecommand \@@href[1]{\endgroup#1\@@endlink}%
\providecommand \@sanitize@url [0]{\catcode `\\12\catcode `\$12\catcode
  `\&12\catcode `\#12\catcode `\^12\catcode `\_12\catcode `\%12\relax}%
\providecommand \@@startlink[1]{}%
\providecommand \@@endlink[0]{}%
\providecommand \url  [0]{\begingroup\@sanitize@url \@url }%
\providecommand \@url [1]{\endgroup\@href {#1}{\urlprefix }}%
\providecommand \urlprefix  [0]{URL }%
\providecommand \Eprint [0]{\href }%
\providecommand \doibase [0]{http://dx.doi.org/}%
\providecommand \selectlanguage [0]{\@gobble}%
\providecommand \bibinfo  [0]{\@secondoftwo}%
\providecommand \bibfield  [0]{\@secondoftwo}%
\providecommand \translation [1]{[#1]}%
\providecommand \BibitemOpen [0]{}%
\providecommand \bibitemStop [0]{}%
\providecommand \bibitemNoStop [0]{.\EOS\space}%
\providecommand \EOS [0]{\spacefactor3000\relax}%
\providecommand \BibitemShut  [1]{\csname bibitem#1\endcsname}%
\let\auto@bib@innerbib\@empty
%</preamble>
\bibitem [{\citenamefont {Boll}\ \emph {et~al.}(2014)\citenamefont {Boll},
\citenamefont {Rouz{\'e}e}, \citenamefont {Adolph}, \citenamefont {Anielski},
\citenamefont {Aquila}, \citenamefont {Bari}, \citenamefont {Bomme},
\citenamefont {Bostedt}, \citenamefont {Bozek}, \citenamefont {Chapman},
\citenamefont {Christensen}, \citenamefont {Coffee}, \citenamefont {Coppola},
\citenamefont {De}, \citenamefont {Decleva}, \citenamefont {Epp},
\citenamefont {Erk}, \citenamefont {Filsinger}, \citenamefont {Foucar},
\citenamefont {Gorkhover}, \citenamefont {Gumprecht}, \citenamefont
{H{\"o}mke}, \citenamefont {Holmegaard}, \citenamefont {Johnsson},
\citenamefont {Kienitz}, \citenamefont {Kierspel}, \citenamefont {Krasniqi},
\citenamefont {K{\"u}hnel}, \citenamefont {Maurer}, \citenamefont
{Messerschmidt}, \citenamefont {Moshammer}, \citenamefont {M{\"u}ller},
\citenamefont {Rudek}, \citenamefont {Savelyev}, \citenamefont {Schlichting},
\citenamefont {Schmidt}, \citenamefont {Scholz}, \citenamefont {Schorb},
\citenamefont {Schulz}, \citenamefont {Seltmann}, \citenamefont {Stener},
\citenamefont {Stern}, \citenamefont {Techert}, \citenamefont {Th{\o}gersen},
\citenamefont {Trippel}, \citenamefont {Viefhaus}, \citenamefont {Vrakking},
\citenamefont {Stapelfeldt}, \citenamefont {K{\"u}pper}, \citenamefont
{Ullrich}, \citenamefont {Rudenko},\ and\ \citenamefont
{Rolles}}]{boll_imaging_2014}%
\BibitemOpen
\bibfield  {author} {\bibinfo {author} {\bibfnamefont {R.}~\bibnamefont
{Boll}}, \bibinfo {author} {\bibfnamefont {A.}~\bibnamefont {Rouz{\'e}e}},
\bibinfo {author} {\bibfnamefont {M.}~\bibnamefont {Adolph}}, \bibinfo
{author} {\bibfnamefont {D.}~\bibnamefont {Anielski}}, \bibinfo {author}
{\bibfnamefont {A.}~\bibnamefont {Aquila}}, \bibinfo {author} {\bibfnamefont
{S.}~\bibnamefont {Bari}}, \bibinfo {author} {\bibfnamefont {C.}~\bibnamefont
{Bomme}}, \bibinfo {author} {\bibfnamefont {C.}~\bibnamefont {Bostedt}},
\bibinfo {author} {\bibfnamefont {J.~D.}\ \bibnamefont {Bozek}}, \bibinfo
{author} {\bibfnamefont {H.~N.}\ \bibnamefont {Chapman}}, \bibinfo {author}
{\bibfnamefont {L.}~\bibnamefont {Christensen}}, \bibinfo {author}
{\bibfnamefont {R.}~\bibnamefont {Coffee}}, \bibinfo {author} {\bibfnamefont
{N.}~\bibnamefont {Coppola}}, \bibinfo {author} {\bibfnamefont
{S.}~\bibnamefont {De}}, \bibinfo {author} {\bibfnamefont {P.}~\bibnamefont
{Decleva}}, \bibinfo {author} {\bibfnamefont {S.~W.}\ \bibnamefont {Epp}},
\bibinfo {author} {\bibfnamefont {B.}~\bibnamefont {Erk}}, \bibinfo {author}
{\bibfnamefont {F.}~\bibnamefont {Filsinger}}, \bibinfo {author}
{\bibfnamefont {L.}~\bibnamefont {Foucar}}, \bibinfo {author} {\bibfnamefont
{T.}~\bibnamefont {Gorkhover}}, \bibinfo {author} {\bibfnamefont
{L.}~\bibnamefont {Gumprecht}}, \bibinfo {author} {\bibfnamefont
{A.}~\bibnamefont {H{\"o}mke}}, \bibinfo {author} {\bibfnamefont
{L.}~\bibnamefont {Holmegaard}}, \bibinfo {author} {\bibfnamefont
{P.}~\bibnamefont {Johnsson}}, \bibinfo {author} {\bibfnamefont {J.~S.}\
\bibnamefont {Kienitz}}, \bibinfo {author} {\bibfnamefont {T.}~\bibnamefont
{Kierspel}}, \bibinfo {author} {\bibfnamefont {F.}~\bibnamefont {Krasniqi}},
\bibinfo {author} {\bibfnamefont {K.-U.}\ \bibnamefont {K{\"u}hnel}},
\bibinfo {author} {\bibfnamefont {J.}~\bibnamefont {Maurer}}, \bibinfo
{author} {\bibfnamefont {M.}~\bibnamefont {Messerschmidt}}, \bibinfo {author}
{\bibfnamefont {R.}~\bibnamefont {Moshammer}}, \bibinfo {author}
{\bibfnamefont {N.~L.~M.}\ \bibnamefont {M{\"u}ller}}, \bibinfo {author}
{\bibfnamefont {B.}~\bibnamefont {Rudek}}, \bibinfo {author} {\bibfnamefont
{E.}~\bibnamefont {Savelyev}}, \bibinfo {author} {\bibfnamefont
{I.}~\bibnamefont {Schlichting}}, \bibinfo {author} {\bibfnamefont
{C.}~\bibnamefont {Schmidt}}, \bibinfo {author} {\bibfnamefont
{F.}~\bibnamefont {Scholz}}, \bibinfo {author} {\bibfnamefont
{S.}~\bibnamefont {Schorb}}, \bibinfo {author} {\bibfnamefont
{J.}~\bibnamefont {Schulz}}, \bibinfo {author} {\bibfnamefont
{J.}~\bibnamefont {Seltmann}}, \bibinfo {author} {\bibfnamefont
{M.}~\bibnamefont {Stener}}, \bibinfo {author} {\bibfnamefont
{S.}~\bibnamefont {Stern}}, \bibinfo {author} {\bibfnamefont
{S.}~\bibnamefont {Techert}}, \bibinfo {author} {\bibfnamefont
{J.}~\bibnamefont {Th{\o}gersen}}, \bibinfo {author} {\bibfnamefont
{S.}~\bibnamefont {Trippel}}, \bibinfo {author} {\bibfnamefont
{J.}~\bibnamefont {Viefhaus}}, \bibinfo {author} {\bibfnamefont
{M.}~\bibnamefont {Vrakking}}, \bibinfo {author} {\bibfnamefont
{H.}~\bibnamefont {Stapelfeldt}}, \bibinfo {author} {\bibfnamefont
{J.}~\bibnamefont {K{\"u}pper}}, \bibinfo {author} {\bibfnamefont
{J.}~\bibnamefont {Ullrich}}, \bibinfo {author} {\bibfnamefont
{A.}~\bibnamefont {Rudenko}}, \ and\ \bibinfo {author} {\bibfnamefont
{D.}~\bibnamefont {Rolles}},\ }\bibfield  {title} {\emph {\bibinfo {title}
{Imaging molecular structure through femtosecond photoelectron diffraction on
aligned and oriented gas-phase molecules}},\ }\href {\doibase
10.1039/C4FD00037D} {\bibfield  {journal} {\bibinfo  {journal} {Faraday
Discussions}\ }\textbf {\bibinfo {volume} {171}},\ \bibinfo {pages} {57}
(\bibinfo {year} {2014})}\BibitemShut {NoStop}%
\end{thebibliography}%
```

Comment: Instead of `{\color{white} \cite{boll_imaging_2014}` you can use `\nocite{boll_imaging_2014}` so you don't have to hide the citation.

Comment: It is a CV, so it requires quite some work to make it look nice and right. Instead of investing time in hacking the bibliography, i would do it by hand.

Answer (score 2):

After a long time, I figured out a solution myself. It can be done by adding

```
\renewcommand{\bibinfo}[2]{
 \noexpandarg
 \exploregroups
 \IfSubStr{#2}{Boll} {\textbf{#2}}{#2}}
```

in the preamble.