# Selectively modify some citations appearance

Tags: biblatex

I am using biblatex with the following setup:

```
\usepackage[style=nejm,hyperref,natbib,backend=biber,maxnames=2,minnames=1]{biblatex}
```

Let us consider, as an example, this citation. (

```
@article{RefWorks:41,
    author={K. J. Koval and J. J. Harrast and J. O. Anglen and J. N. Weinstein},
    year={2008},
    month={Sep},
    title={Fractures of the distal part of the radius. The evolution of practice over time. Where's the evidence?},
    journal={The Journal of bone and joint surgery.American volume},
    volume={90},
    number={9},
    pages={1855-1861},
}
```

When I am citing with \textcite{RefWorks:41}, I would like to make the name part `Koval et al.` appearing such as `\textbf{\textsf{\textsc{Koval et al.}}}`. In the meantime, the bibstyle should remain unchanged. In addition, it should be applied to selected citations (not to all, but to some specific ones depending the context.)
Any ideas?Suggestions?

Edit:
Further explanation:
given the author key in the bib file author={K. J. Koval and J. J. Harrast and J. O. Anglen and J. N. Weinstein}, I would like to make the the "author" part of the output of \textcite bold whatever it is. I mean, with maxnames=2,minnames=1, the output should be **Koval et al.** [25], with maxnames=6,minnames=3  it should be **Koval, Harrast, Anglen e Weinstein** [25] with the latter part (25) left unchanged.

Also, if a reference is cited more than one time, i would like to choose which citation should be bolded (not all of them).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make specific author bold using biblatex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73136/make-specific-author-bold-using-biblatex)

Comment: No, i think it is not. I am not searching to make bold a specific name or author,but to have the possibility of making the citations bold when I think it is necessary (that is much more general). Second, the question was specific to the bibliography, but I want to modify the behaviour in the text

Comment: Ok, sorry about that. Yes, you're right this is not a duplicate.  Other voters: please do NOT vote to close!

Comment: Do you just need a single particular name to be bolded or an arbitrary list of names?

Comment: why is the duplicate banner still at the top?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally, this would not take more than a few lines of code, the `nejm` style is based on `numeric-comp` though, and `numeric-comp` has a very peculiar handling of `textcite` to make sure everything looks nice.
So we will have to copy quite some code for a very minor modification.

Our new bibmcaro `boldtextcite` is a verbatim copy of `textcite`'s bibmacro with the `\mkbibbold` wrapper added around `\printnames{labelnames}`.
`\cbx@boldtextcite` is a helper to define `\boldtextcite` in `\DeclareCiteCommand{\boldtextcite}`.

```
\makeatletter
\newbibmacro*{boldtextcite}{%
  \iffieldequals{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:comp}}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:dump}%
     \ifbool{cbx:parens}
       {\bibclosebracket\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
       {}%
     \iffirstcitekey
       {}
       {\textcitedelim}%
     \usebibmacro{cite:init}%
     \ifnameundef{labelname}
       {\printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}
       {\mkbibbold{\printnames{labelname}}}%
     \global\booltrue{cbx:parens}%
     \addspace\bibopenbracket%
     \ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{1}
       {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
       {}%
     \usebibmacro{cite:comp}%
     \stepcounter{textcitecount}%
     \savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\cbx@boldtextcite}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{boldtextcite}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:dump}%
   \usebibmacro{postnote}%
   \ifbool{cbx:parens}
     {\bibclosebracket\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
     {}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\boldtextcite}[\cbx@textcite@init\cbx@boldtextcite]
  {\gdef\cbx@savedkeys{}%
   \citetrackerfalse%
   \pagetrackerfalse%
   \DeferNextCitekeyHook%
   \usebibmacro{cite:init}}
  {\ifthenelse{\iffirstcitekey\AND\value{multicitetotal}>0}
     {\protected@xappto\cbx@savedcites{()(\thefield{multipostnote})}%
      \global\clearfield{multipostnote}}
     {}%
   \xappto\cbx@savedkeys{\thefield{entrykey},}%
   \iffieldequals{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}
     {}
     {\stepcounter{textcitetotal}%
      \savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}}}
  {}
  {\protected@xappto\cbx@savedcites{%
     [\thefield{prenote}][\thefield{postnote}]{\cbx@savedkeys}}}
\makeatother
```

We now have to cite commands, the standard `\textcite` and `\boldtextcite` that turns the names bold.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[style=nejm,hyperref,natbib,backend=biber,maxnames=2,minnames=1]{biblatex}


\makeatletter
\newbibmacro*{boldtextcite}{%
  \iffieldequals{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:comp}}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:dump}%
     \ifbool{cbx:parens}
       {\bibclosebracket\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
       {}%
     \iffirstcitekey
       {}
       {\textcitedelim}%
     \usebibmacro{cite:init}%
     \ifnameundef{labelname}
       {\printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}
       {\mkbibbold{\printnames{labelname}}}%
     \global\booltrue{cbx:parens}%
     \addspace\bibopenbracket%
     \ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{1}
       {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
       {}%
     \usebibmacro{cite:comp}%
     \stepcounter{textcitecount}%
     \savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\cbx@boldtextcite}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{boldtextcite}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:dump}%
   \usebibmacro{postnote}%
   \ifbool{cbx:parens}
     {\bibclosebracket\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
     {}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\boldtextcite}[\cbx@textcite@init\cbx@boldtextcite]
  {\gdef\cbx@savedkeys{}%
   \citetrackerfalse%
   \pagetrackerfalse%
   \DeferNextCitekeyHook%
   \usebibmacro{cite:init}}
  {\ifthenelse{\iffirstcitekey\AND\value{multicitetotal}>0}
     {\protected@xappto\cbx@savedcites{()(\thefield{multipostnote})}%
      \global\clearfield{multipostnote}}
     {}%
   \xappto\cbx@savedkeys{\thefield{entrykey},}%
   \iffieldequals{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}
     {}
     {\stepcounter{textcitetotal}%
      \savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}}}
  {}
  {\protected@xappto\cbx@savedcites{%
     [\thefield{prenote}][\thefield{postnote}]{\cbx@savedkeys}}}
\makeatother

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
\textcite{wilde,companion}

\boldtextcite{wilde,companion}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you!. Any ideas about \adding \textsf{\textsc{ to the bold? The desired result should be`\textbf{\textsf{\textsc{Koval et al.}}}`

Comment: @thunder1123 In the first macro you will find the line `{\mkbibbold{\printnames{labelname}}}`. You can add any mark-up modifications you like there. But as far as I know, the `lmodern` fonts cannot deal with `\textbf{\textsf{\textsc` - there is no bold small caps version. I'm not too sure that you will actually find a font that has all the three features together. (Linux Libertine and its companion maybe?)

Comment: @thunder1123 I just had a look, `lmodern` and the standard font do not support this font combination (`Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.`), but `libertine` is fine with it. I used `{\textsf{\textsc{\mkbibbold{\printnames{labelname}}}}}%`. Since `\textsf` and `\textsc` do not have a `biblatex`-y equivalent.