# Formatting inside .bib files with Biblatex

Tags: biblatex

I'm trying to manually put formatting codes into the fields of my .bib file, but the final compile step crashes with a `Missing \endcsname inserted` error on the `\printbibliography` line.  In particular, I need to bold particular names, which may be in an arbitrary position in the author list.  The problems seems to be with `\textbf{Name}` breaking the final compile.

I also tried `{\bfseries Name}`, but that bolds all the names afterwards.

(Background, I need to do for the publications list of my CV to put it in a particular required format.  I'd rather use `biblatex` than manually format everything.)

Below is my MNWE.  I'm compiling with `pdflatex; biber; pdflatex` on a MikTex-64bit distribution.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
% biblatex version 3.3
% biber version 2.4

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{Article1,
author = {Last1\textsuperscript{*}, First1 and \textbf{Last2}, \textbf{First2} and Last3, First3},
year = {2016},
title = {The Title},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\nocite{*}


\begin{document}

Star\textsuperscript{*} indicates student author.  \textbf{Bold} indicates corresponding author.
\subsection*{Desired output}
[1]  First1 Last1\textsuperscript{*}, \textbf{First2} \textbf{Last2},  and First3 Last3. \emph{The Title}. 2016.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: This may be a duplicate - see here for example: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73136/make-specific-author-bold-using-biblatex

Comment: You should not include formatting commands into name fields (it is sometimes necessary for other fields, but can often be avoided). You can apply special formatting for certain names (such as *bold my name*) but what you want seems trickier.

Comment: @PLK This is different because the bolded name may be different for each entry.

Comment: I assume the names could come in random order? So it would not just be possible to print the student authors first and then the corresponding authors, because that would not be the proper order on the work itself

Comment: @moewe Yes, the order needs to be identical to the order on the publication itself.

Comment: Don't think its going to be that easy ... Maybe one could cook something up with the new `biblatexml` name formats (but then you will have to switch from `.bib` to the new format ...). Or with some extra name fields, which would introduce massive redundancy, I guess.

Comment: @moeve I have an idea. What is the counter of authors when the namelist is processed?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Ohhh, ein Rätsel ... `\value{listcount}`?

Comment: Also, I'm sorting by date, so I'm not concerned with the formatting codes influencing the sort by name.

Comment: Well, you'll find the usual `\value{listcount}` and `\value{listtotal}` defined in name formats.

Comment: There will likely be a new feature in 3.4 called "annotations" which allows you annotate any piece of input data and pass this through to the biblatex style where you can do what you like with the annotation information. This will be first implemented for the biblatexml format as that is more suitable for such things. Hacking it into the bibtex format may also happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a more general way to handle this now in biblatex 3.4/biber 2.5 through data annotations since this is not an uncommon request and we need a way of allowing ad-hoc attachment of semantic information to pieces of data which doesn't require messing about with internals. Annotation in `biblatexml` is straighforward and done by XML attributes:

```
<bltx:entries xmlns:bltx="http://biblatex-biber.sourceforge.net/biblatexml">
  <bltx:entry id="Article1" entrytype="misc">
    <bltx:names type="author">
      <bltx:name>
        <bltx:namepart type="given" initial="F">First1</bltx:namepart>
        <bltx:namepart type="family" initial="L" annotation="student">Last1</bltx:namepart>
      </bltx:name>
      <bltx:name annotation="corresponding">
        <bltx:namepart type="given" initial="F">First2</bltx:namepart>
        <bltx:namepart type="family" initial="L">Last2</bltx:namepart>
      </bltx:name>
      <bltx:name>
        <bltx:namepart type="given" initial="F">First3</bltx:namepart>
        <bltx:namepart type="family" initial="L">Last3</bltx:namepart>
      </bltx:name>
    </bltx:names>
  </bltx:entry>
</bltx:entries>
```

With `bibtex` data sources, it's a bit uglier but relatively simple:

```
@MISC{Article1,
  AUTHOR    = {Last1, First1 and Last2, First2 and Last3, First3},
  AUTHOR+an = {1:family=student;2=corresponding},
}
```

and then you can use these annotations in formatting directives via three new macros:

```
\renewbibmacro*{name:given-family}[4]{%
  \usebibmacro{name:delim}{#2#3#1}%
  \usebibmacro{name:hook}{#2#3#1}%
  \ifdefvoid{#2}{}{\mkbibnamegiven{#2}\isdot\bibnamedelimd}%
  \ifdefvoid{#3}{}{%
    \mkbibnameprefix{#3}\isdot
    \ifprefchar
      {}
      {\ifuseprefix{\bibnamedelimc}{\bibnamedelimd}}}%
  \mkbibnamefamily{#1}%
  \ifpartannotation{family}{student}
    {\textsuperscript{*}}
    {}%
    \isdot
  \ifdefvoid{#4}{}{\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnamesuffix{#4}\isdot}}

\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamegiven}[1]{%
  \ifitemannotation{corresponding}
    {\textbf{#1}}
    {#1}}

\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{%
  \ifitemannotation{corresponding}
    {\textbf{#1}}
    {#1}}
```

This gives you the output you wanted without putting markup in the data and via semantic annotations. The DEV 3.4 PDF manual has the details. It needs the latest `biber` 2.5 release too.

Comment: I was only recently able to try this, now that biblatex 3.4 and biber 2.5 have hit the MikTeX distribution.  It works well and makes my .bib files more transportable because the formatting is now separated from the data.  Nice work.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to inject commands into the name processing which are only used for certain keys + author counts. For the \textsuperscript it is not necessary but I'm inserting another one anyway as proof of concept. It is probably possible to store the info in the bib-file and one can certainly improve the interface:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{Article1,
author = {Last1\textsuperscript{*}, First1 and Last2, First2 and Last3, First3},
year = {2016},
title = {The Title},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
% biblatex version 3.3
% biber version 2.4

\DeclareNameFormat{given-family}{%
  \nameparts{#1}%
  \ifgiveninits
    {\usebibmacro{name:given-family}
      {\namepartfamily}
      {\namepartgiveni}
      {\namepartprefix}
      {\namepartsuffix}}
    {{\csname key-\thefield{entrykey}-\the\value{listcount}-font\endcsname
      \usebibmacro{name:given-family}
      {\namepartfamily}
      {\namepartgiven}
      {\namepartprefix}
      {\namepartsuffix}%
      \csname key-\thefield{entrykey}-\the\value{listcount}-suffix\endcsname
      }}%
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\makeatletter
\@namedef{key-Article1-2-font}{\bfseries}
\@namedef{key-Article1-1-suffix}{\textsuperscript{*}}
\makeatletter

\begin{document}
\cite{Article1}
Star\textsuperscript{*} indicates student author.  \textbf{Bold} indicates corresponding author.
\subsection*{Desired output}
[1]  First1 Last1\textsuperscript{*}, \textbf{First2} \textbf{Last2},  and First3 Last3. \emph{The Title}. 2016.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think I see how this works, but let me check to see if I understand.  Does the information about which author is bolded goes in the block of `\@namedef` commands before `\begin{document}`?

Comment: Yes. The command "name" is `key-bibkey-authorcount-font`  (the fix words key and font are only there to avoid clashes with other commands).

Comment: Is there any way to embed this info in the `.bib` file instead of the `.tex` file, perhaps by defining a new field?

Comment: As I wrote: probably. Actually I'm certain that it is possible. You need some other name list where you can pull the info from. But I don't have the time now.

Comment: This worked, but I now prefer the solution by @PLK now that I have been able to try biblatex 3.4 and biber 2.5, which were recently added to the MikTeX distribution.