# How to add notes to authors in BibLaTeX?

Tags: biblatex

When e.g. citing a film, I think using the film's director and producer as the author of the work is appropriate. Thus I would like to add their role in the production behind their names in parentheses. However doing

```
author = {Stanton, Andrew (Director) and Walters, Graham (Producer)}
```

will put `(Director)` as the second given name when using a reference style starting with the first name. Is there a way to represent this that will work independently of the style of the bibliography?

Comment: You can use annotations. See the documentation "3.6 Data Annotations" and http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/304968/2388

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a way to do this, but you may find yourself mired quite quickly.

The standard schemes have some "uncommitted" fields `editora` and `editoratype` and `editorb` etc which can be used for non-standard "roles". By default they get printed after the title, as "by ..." using a `bibstring` called `byx` where `x` is the relevant `type`, so if `editoratype` is `redactor`, it gets printed using the `byredactor` string.

To leverage this, in the standard styles, you need (a) to define a suitable `by...` string, because the ones you want are not pre-defined, and (b) to use it appropriately in the `.bib` file. It's easier to explain by example below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
  @film{nemo,
    editora = {Stanton, Andrew},
    editoratype = {director},
    editorb = {Walters, Graham},
    editorbtype = {producer},
    title = {Finding Nemo},
    date = 2003,
    }
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=verbose]{biblatex}

\NewBibliographyString{bydirector, bydirectors, byproducer, byproducers}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  bydirector = {Directed by},
  bydirectors = {Directed by},
  byproducer = {Produced by},
  byproducers = {Produced by},
}


\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Produces

[image: image of result]

However, if you pursue this you will always certainly find yourself wanting to adapt the whole citation system to cope properly with films. (I was surprised, frankly, that `@film` even worked!) I haven't checked, but I have a feeling that the `biblatex-chicago` systems have something properly worked out for this. And there may well be other specialised systems, which if you want to use this a lot are probably worth pursuing.

Comment: `authortype` is also useful.

Comment: `biblatex-chicago` indeed has some support for film types (`@video`), and apparently already defines `director` and `producer` bibstrings. There is also `biblatex-fiwi` ('fiwi' for Filmwissenschaften) with extensive support for all kinds of these things (`@movie`/`@video`), but the documentation is in German.