# Bibliography counters, reverse order numbering and keywords

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber, keywords

Please see the mwe below

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber,%
isbn=false,%
style=numeric,%
sorting=ydnt,%
giveninits=true,% initials of first names
maxbibnames=20,%
defernumbers,%
labeldateparts,% for academic cv
locallabelwidth% for academic cv
]{biblatex} 

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname_a.bib}
@Article{Fabulous2016a,
  author  = {Fabulous, Jason},
  title   = {How to be fabulous - The Story of My Life},
  journal = {Fancy Journal},
  year    = {2016},
  volume  = {56},
  number  = {3},
  pages   = {1-99},
  keywords = {include},
}

@Article{FabulousFaulkner2019a,
  author  = {Fabulous, Jason and Faulkner, Trent},
  title   = {One Fabulous Moment after Another -  A chat with my buddy Trent},
  journal = {Journal},
  year    = {2018},
  volume  = {56},
  number  = {3},
  pages   = {1-99},
  keywords = {},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname_b.bib}
@Article{Fuca2019a,
  author  = {Fuca, Wanda},
  title   = {Ridges, Plates and Seamounts},
  journal = {Journal 2},
  year    = {2019},
  volume  = {56},
  number  = {3},
  pages   = {1-99},
  keywords = {include},
}

@Article{Fuca2015a,
  author  = {Fuca, Wanda},
  title   = {How to truly know whether your parents were Hippies},
  journal = {Journal},
  year    = {2015},
  volume  = {56},
  number  = {3},
  pages   = {1-99},
  keywords = {include},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{cvsectionnum.tex}
% define a bibenvironment for an numbered bib entry
\defbibenvironment{bibenvcvsectionnum}%
{\list%
{\printtext[labelnumberwidth]{%
\printfield{labelprefix}%
\printfield{labelnumber}}}%
{\setlength{\leftmargin}{\bibhang}%
\setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
\setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}}%
{\endlist}%
{\item}%

% cvsectionnum
\newcommand\cvsectionnum[3]{%
\section*{#1}%
\begin{refsection}[#2]%
\nocite{*}%
\printbibliography[heading=none,env=bibenvcvsectionnum,#3]%
\end{refsection}%
}%
\end{filecontents}


\begin{filecontents}{reverse_order_bib_entry_numbering.tex}
\AtDataInput{%
\csnumgdef{entrycount:\therefsection}{%
\csuse{entrycount:\therefsection}+1}}%
%
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumber}{\mkbibdesc{#1}}%
\newrobustcmd*{\mkbibdesc}[1]{%
\number\numexpr\csuse{entrycount:\therefsection}+1-#1\relax}%
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname_a.bib}%
\addbibresource{\jobname_b.bib}%

% declare section names
\def\sectiona{J's Publications}%
\def\sectionb{Wanda's Pulications}%


% definition of `cvsectionnum'
\input{cvsectionnum.tex}

% reverse order numbering
\input{reverse_order_bib_entry_numbering.tex}


\begin{document}

% J
\cvsectionnum{\sectiona}{\jobname_a.bib}{keyword={include}}%

% Wanda
\cvsectionnum{\sectionb}{\jobname_b.bib}{keyword={include}}%

\end{document}
```

Here is what the output looks like:

[image]

The question is, how to make J's bib entry have a 1 as a label instead of a 2?  Via the keywords functionality, we are filtering each of the publication lists passed to the `cvsectionnum` command, yet it seems that the counter is being determined before filtering, hence the out of range and non-sequential label.

[This post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/499980/can-this-custom-makeauthorbold-macro-be-made-more-robust) might also provide additional context.

Comment: Adjusted the mwe to generated externalized macros with `filecontents`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use an additional counter to count the entries, this requires two compilations.

The filecontents package is obsolete, I replaced this with the [overwrite] option.

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage[backend=biber,%
isbn=false,%
style=numeric,%
sorting=ydnt,%
giveninits=true,% initials of first names
maxbibnames=20,%
defernumbers,%
labeldateparts,% for academic cv
locallabelwidth% for academic cv
]{biblatex}



\begin{filecontents}{\jobname_a.bib}
@Article{Fabulous2016a,
  author  = {Fabulous, Jason},
  title   = {How to be fabulous - The Story of My Life},
  journal = {Fancy Journal},
  year    = {2016},
  volume  = {56},
  number  = {3},
  pages   = {1-99},
  keywords = {include},
}

@Article{FabulousFaulkner2019a,
  author  = {Fabulous, Jason and Faulkner, Trent},
  title   = {One Fabulous Moment after Another -  A chat with my buddy Trent},
  journal = {Journal},
  year    = {2018},
  volume  = {56},
  number  = {3},
  pages   = {1-99},
  keywords = {},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname_b.bib}
@Article{Fuca2019a,
  author  = {Fuca, Wanda},
  title   = {Ridges, Plates and Seamounts},
  journal = {Journal 2},
  year    = {2019},
  volume  = {56},
  number  = {3},
  pages   = {1-99},
  keywords = {include},
}

@Article{Fuca2015a,
  author  = {Fuca, Wanda},
  title   = {How to truly know whether your parents were Hippies},
  journal = {Journal},
  year    = {2015},
  volume  = {56},
  number  = {3},
  pages   = {1-99},
  keywords = {include},
}
\end{filecontents}
\newcounter{mybibcount}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{cvsectionnum.tex}
% define a bibenvironment for an numbered bib entry
\defbibenvironment{bibenvcvsectionnum}%
{\setcounter{mybibcount}{-1}\list%
{\stepcounter{mybibcount}\printtext[labelnumberwidth]{%
\printfield{labelprefix}%
\printfield{labelnumber}}}%
{\setlength{\leftmargin}{\bibhang}%
\setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
\setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}}%
{\refstepcounter{mybibcount}\label{bibcount\therefsection}\endlist}%
{\item}%

% cvsectionnum
\newcommand\cvsectionnum[3]{%
\section*{#1}%
\begin{refsection}[#2]%
\nocite{*}%
\printbibliography[heading=none,env=bibenvcvsectionnum,#3]%
\end{refsection}%
}%
\end{filecontents}


\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{reverse_order_bib_entry_numbering.tex}
\AtDataInput{%
\csnumgdef{entrycount:\therefsection}{%
\getrefnumber{bibcount\therefsection}}}%
%
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumber}{\mkbibdesc{#1}}%
\newrobustcmd*{\mkbibdesc}[1]{%
\number\numexpr\csuse{entrycount:\therefsection}+1-#1\relax}%
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname_a.bib}%
\addbibresource{\jobname_b.bib}%

% declare section names
\def\sectiona{J's Publications}%
\def\sectionb{Wanda's Pulications}%


% definition of `cvsectionnum'
\input{cvsectionnum.tex}

% reverse order numbering
\input{reverse_order_bib_entry_numbering.tex}


\begin{document}
% J
\cvsectionnum{\sectiona}{\jobname_a.bib}{keyword={include}}%
% Wanda
\cvsectionnum{\sectionb}{\jobname_b.bib}{keyword={include}}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Kind thanks for this suggestion; works very nicely!

Answer (score 2):

The problem comes from

```
{\printtext[labelnumberwidth]{%
\printfield{labelprefix}%
\printfield{labelnumber}}}%
```

that I changed into

```
{\printfield[labelnumberwidth]{labelnumber}}%
```

by taking some inspiration in the [biblatex User Guide](http://ctan.cs.uu.nl/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) p. 156.

The result is:

[image]

Comment: This solution fulfills one criterion (eliminating labels which don't start at one and potential non-sequential gaps between labels), but note that we're trying to implement reverse order numbering.  Some choose to implement reverse order numbering this because they're attuned to the fact that some others like to count and are lazy.  If you number in reverse order, the reader only needs to glance at the first entry to guage the total number of entries in the list.

Comment: Edited title of question to reflect the importance of reverse order numbering.

Comment: `\printtext[labelnumberwidth]{%
        \printfield{labelprefix}%
        \printfield{labelnumber}}` (modulo line breaks) is a perfectly fine idiom. Indeed, dropping `labelprefix` means that this function is no longer supported in the bibliography.