# Bold certain authors and dagger other authors

Tags: biblatex

I am working on a promotion and tenure CV's publication section. I would like the following features:

1. Make certain authors bold (myself)
2. Dagger (\dag) certain authors (students)
3. Double dagger certain authors (postdocs)

I was able to make the first one work by:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric,defernumbers=true,sorting=ydnt,maxbibnames=99]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\newcommand{\makeauthorbold}[1]{%
  \DeclareNameFormat{author}{%
    \ifthenelse{\value{listcount}=1}
    {%
      {\expandafter\ifstrequal\expandafter{\namepartfamily}{#1}{\mkbibbold{\namepartfamily\addcomma\addspace \namepartgiveni}}{\namepartfamily\addcomma\addspace \namepartgiveni}}
      %
    }{\ifnumless{\value{listcount}}{\value{liststop}}
        {\expandafter\ifstrequal\expandafter{\namepartfamily}{#1}{\mkbibbold{\addcomma\addspace \namepartfamily\addcomma\addspace \namepartgiveni}}{\addcomma\addspace \namepartfamily\addcomma\addspace \namepartgiveni}}
        {\expandafter\ifstrequal\expandafter{\namepartfamily}{#1}{\mkbibbold{\addcomma\addspace \namepartfamily\addcomma\addspace \namepartgiveni\addcomma\isdot}}{\addcomma\addspace \namepartfamily\addcomma\addspace \namepartgiveni\addcomma\isdot}}%
      }
    \ifthenelse{\value{listcount}<\value{liststop}}
    {\addcomma\space}
  }
}
\makeauthorbold{MyLastName}
```

I originally hoped to repeat a similar process for points two and three, and creating a `\makeauthordag` and `\makeauthorddag` commands but only the last one will work (seems to be overwriting previous commands actions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would work with name hashes here instead of string comparison.

We can parametrise the approach recommended in [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/416416/35864) to [Make specific author bold using biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/73136/35864) to allow for several independent lists of hashes.

With `\markname{<marker>}{<list of names>}` we can define names that will be marked as `<marker>`. We can then test for this marker with `\ifnamemarked{<marker>}{<true>}{<false>}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\makeatletter
\def\nhblx@bibfile@name{\jobname -nhblx.bib}
\newwrite\nhblx@bibfile
\immediate\openout\nhblx@bibfile=\nhblx@bibfile@name

\immediate\write\nhblx@bibfile{%
  @comment{Auto-generated file}\blx@nl}

\newcounter{nhblx@name}
\setcounter{nhblx@name}{0}

\newcommand*{\nhblx@writenametobib}[2]{%
  \ifcsundef{nhblx@#1list}
    {\csdef{nhblx@#1list}{}}
    {}%
  \stepcounter{nhblx@name}%
  \edef\nhblx@tmp@nocite{%
    \noexpand\AfterPreamble{%
      \noexpand\setbox0\noexpand\vbox{%
        \noexpand\def\noexpand\nhblx@listname{nhblx@#1list}%
        \noexpand\nhblx@getmethehash{nhblx@name@\the\value{nhblx@name}}}}%
  }%
  \nhblx@tmp@nocite
  \immediate\write\nhblx@bibfile{%
    @misc{nhblx@name@\the\value{nhblx@name}, author = {\unexpanded{#2}}, %
          options = {dataonly=true},}%
  }%
}

\AtEndDocument{%
  \closeout\nhblx@bibfile}

\addbibresource{\nhblx@bibfile@name}

\DeclareNameFormat{nhblx@hashextract}{%
  \xifinlistcs{\thefield{hash}}{\nhblx@listname}
    {}
    {\listcsxadd{\nhblx@listname}{\thefield{hash}}}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\nhblx@getmethehash}
  {}
  {\typeout{\nhblx@listname}\printnames[nhblx@hashextract][1-999]{author}}
  {}
  {}

\newcommand*{\markname}[1]{\forcsvlist{\nhblx@writenametobib{#1}}}
\newcommand*{\resetmark}[1]{\csdef{nhblx@#1list}{}}

\newcommand*{\ifnamemarked}[1]{%
  \xifinlistcs{\thefield{hash}}{nhblx@#1list}}
\makeatother

\newcommand*{\studentorpostdoc}[1]{%
  \ifnamemarked{student}{\dag}{}%
  \ifnamemarked{postdoc}{\ddag}{}%
  #1}

\newcommand*{\nameformatter}[1]{%
  \ifnamemarked{me}
    {\mkbibbold{#1}}
    {\studentorpostdoc{#1}}}

\DeclareNameWrapperFormat{nameformatter}{%
  \renewcommand*{\mkbibcompletename}{\nameformatter}%
  #1}

\DeclareNameWrapperAlias{sortname}{default}
\DeclareNameWrapperAlias{default}{nameformatter}

\markname{me}{{Sigfridsson, Emma}}
\markname{student}{Philipp Jaff{\'e}}
\markname{postdoc}{Ulf Ryde}

\begin{document}
\nocite{sigfridsson,jaffe}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Bibliography with bold, daggers and double daggers.]

Comment: Turns out, something similar can be found in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/585723/35864.