# Unwanted offset when using biblatex's printbibliography and author bolding via xstring+etoolbox

Tags: biblatex, etoolbox, xstring

I'm trying to bold my name in a publication list. After an embarrassing amount of time/experimentation I have something I'm happy with via `etoolbox` and `xstring`:

```
\renewcommand{\mkbibnamegiven}[1]{\ifboolexpr{(test {\IfSubStr{\namepartfamily}{Knowles}} and (test {\IfSubStr{\namepartgiven}{David}})}{\mkbibbold{#1}}{#1}}
\renewcommand{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\mkbibnamegiven{#1}}
```

However, this results in an odd indentation artefact when I do `printbibliography` twice:
[image]

Am I doing something incorrect with the macro or is this an actual bug? Thanks! MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
@ARTICLE{Isaev2023-ax,
  title    = "Investigating {RNA} splicing as a source of cellular diversity
              using a binomial mixture model",
  author   = "Isaev, Keren and Knowles, David A",
  journal  = "bioRxiv",
  year     =  2023,
  Keywords = {Working}
}

@ARTICLE{Brown2023-fm,
  title     = "MCFA",
  author    = "Brown†, Brielin C and Knowles†, David A and Lappalainen†, Tuuli",
  journal   = "Cell Genomics",
  year      =  2023,
      bibbase_note = {†Co-corresponding},
  Keywords = {Genetics}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{test.bib}

\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\renewcommand{\mkbibnamegiven}[1]{\ifboolexpr{(test {\IfSubStr{\namepartfamily}{Knowles}} and (test {\IfSubStr{\namepartgiven}{David}})}{\mkbibbold{#1}}{#1}}
\renewcommand{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\mkbibnamegiven{#1}}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[title=Journal articles, type=article, keyword=Genetics]
\noindent % doesn't help
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\printbibliography[title=Working, type=article, keyword=Working]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The round brackets aren't properly matched inside the `\ifboolexpr`. Unfortunately, `etoolbox` does not warn about it, it just messes up the surrounding typesetting.

The following MWE (without any round brackets - they were not required here) works as intended

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{xstring}

\renewcommand{\mkbibnamegiven}[1]{%
  \ifboolexpr{    test {\IfSubStr{\namepartfamily}{Knowles}}
              and test {\IfSubStr{\namepartgiven}{David}}}
    {\mkbibbold{#1}}
    {#1}}
\renewcommand{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\mkbibnamegiven{#1}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{Isaev2023-ax,
  title    = "Investigating {RNA} splicing as a source of cellular diversity
              using a binomial mixture model",
  author   = "Isaev, Keren and Knowles, David A",
  journal  = "bioRxiv",
  year     =  2023,
  Keywords = {Working}
}
@ARTICLE{Brown2023-fm,
  title     = "MCFA",
  author    = "Brown†, Brielin C and Knowles†, David A and Lappalainen†, Tuuli",
  journal   = "Cell Genomics",
  year      =  2023,
  bibbase_note = {†Co-corresponding},
  Keywords = {Genetics}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[title=Journal articles, type=article, keyword=Genetics]
\printbibliography[title=Working, type=article, keyword=Working]
\end{document}
```

[image: Properly aligned entries in bibliography]

Comment: Note that there are other ways to bold certain authors that don't rely on `xstring`. (`xstring` can be a bit tricky at times.) See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/73136/35864.

Comment: Thank you so much. I started with those options but couldn't get anything I was happy with for bolding multiple authors.