# Make bold a name containing an empty space in the bibliography biblatex

Tags: biblatex, overleaf, bold

I am implementing the first solution presented [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73136/make-specific-author-bold-using-biblatex/73246#73246) to make bold a selection of names in the biblatex bibliography.

The problem I have is with names containing an empty space " ". The solution does not apply then. Example `Le Texier`:

```
@article{schindlerHowFarPeople2022,
  title = {How Far Do People Travel to Use Urban Green Space? {{A}} Comparison of Three {{European}} Cities},
  author = {Schindler, Mirjam and Le Texier, Marion and Caruso, Geoffrey},
  date = {2022-04-01},
  journaltitle = {Applied Geography},
  volume = {141},
  pages = {102673},
  doi = {10.1016/j.apgeog.2022.102673},
}
```

I formed the filter based on the example given in the proposed solution:

```
    \forcsvlist{\listadd\boldnames} %this is the model of filter
      {{Herrmann, Wolfgang~A.}, {Herrmann, W.~A.}, {Herrmann, Wolfgang\bibnamedelima A.},
      {Herrmann, W\bibinitperiod\bibinitdelim A\bibinitperiod}}
   \forcsvlist{\listadd\boldnames} %this is my implementation of the filter
      {{Le Texier, Marion}, {Le~Texier, Marion}, {Le Texier, M.}, {Texier, M\bibinitperiod}}
```

The filters work for all the author names, but fails for this particular name containing an empty space.

Comment: Does `{{Le Texier}, Marion}` or `{{Le~Texier}, Marion}` work?

Comment: thanks @Mico, but none of your proposed solutions work for me

Comment: There is an annotation feature which is designed to do this sort of thing: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73136/make-specific-author-bold-using-biblatex/304968#304968

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Names with spaces in them can be tricky in the string-based approach. If you check the `.bbl` file, you'll see that Biber produces

```
    {{hash=31cbf23407084cad2911631ec94eba70}{%
       family={Le\bibnamedelima Texier},
       familyi={L\bibinitperiod\bibinitdelim T\bibinitperiod},
       given={Marion},
       giveni={M\bibinitperiod}}}%
```

that's all `biblatex` sees, so you'll have to use `Le\bibnamedelima Texier` instead of `Le Texier`

```
\forcsvlist{\listadd\boldnames}
  {{Le\bibnamedelima Texier, Marion}, {Le\bibnamedelima Texier, M\bibinitperiod}}
```

This works as shown in the following MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\newbibmacro*{name:bold}[2]{%
  \edef\blx@tmp@name{\expandonce#1, \expandonce#2}%
  \def\do##1{\ifdefstring{\blx@tmp@name}{##1}{\bfseries\listbreak}{}}%
  \dolistloop{\boldnames}}
\newcommand*{\boldnames}{}
\makeatother

\xpretobibmacro{name:family}{\begingroup\usebibmacro{name:bold}{#1}{#2}}{}{}
\xpretobibmacro{name:given-family}{\begingroup\usebibmacro{name:bold}{#1}{#2}}{}{}
\xpretobibmacro{name:family-given}{\begingroup\usebibmacro{name:bold}{#1}{#2}}{}{}
\xpretobibmacro{name:delim}{\begingroup\normalfont}{}{}

\xapptobibmacro{name:family}{\endgroup}{}{}
\xapptobibmacro{name:given-family}{\endgroup}{}{}
\xapptobibmacro{name:family-given}{\endgroup}{}{}
\xapptobibmacro{name:delim}{\endgroup}{}{}


\forcsvlist{\listadd\boldnames}
  {{Le\bibnamedelima Texier, Marion}, {Le\bibnamedelima Texier, M\bibinitperiod}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{schindlerHowFarPeople2022,
  title        = {How Far Do People Travel to Use Urban Green Space?
                  A Comparison of Three {European} Cities},
  author       = {Schindler, Mirjam and Le Texier, Marion
                  and Caruso, Geoffrey},
  date         = {2022-04-01},
  journaltitle = {Applied Geography},
  volume       = {141},
  pages        = {102673},
  doi          = {10.1016/j.apgeog.2022.102673},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

% just for demonstration
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{maxnames=99,giveninits}
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given/given-family}

\begin{document}
\nocite{schindlerHowFarPeople2022}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Schindler, M., M. Le Texier, and G. Caruso. “How Far Do People Travel to Use Urban Green Space? A Comparison of Three European Cities”. In: Applied Geography 141 (Apr. 1, 2022), p. 102673. doi: 10.1016/j.apgeog.2022.102673.]

---

Issues like this are why I warmly recommend a hash-based approach as implemented in [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/416416/35864) to [Make specific author bold using biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/73136/35864).

This would then look like the following, where you can pass the name to `\addboldnames` just as you would write it in the `.bib` file.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric]{biblatex}

\makeatletter
\def\nhblx@bibfile@name{\jobname -nhblx.bib}
\newwrite\nhblx@bibfile
\immediate\openout\nhblx@bibfile=\nhblx@bibfile@name

\immediate\write\nhblx@bibfile{%
  @comment{Auto-generated file}\blx@nl}

\newcounter{nhblx@name}
\setcounter{nhblx@name}{0}

\newcommand*{\nhblx@writenametobib}[1]{%
  \stepcounter{nhblx@name}%
  \edef\nhblx@tmp@nocite{%
    \noexpand\AfterPreamble{%
      \noexpand\setbox0\noexpand\vbox{%
        \noexpand\nhblx@getmethehash{nhblx@name@\the\value{nhblx@name}}}}%
  }%
  \nhblx@tmp@nocite
  \immediate\write\nhblx@bibfile{%
    @misc{nhblx@name@\the\value{nhblx@name}, author = {\unexpanded{#1}}, %
          options = {dataonly=true},}%
  }%
}

\AtEndDocument{%
  \closeout\nhblx@bibfile}

\addbibresource{\nhblx@bibfile@name}

\newcommand*{\nhblx@boldhashes}{}
\DeclareNameFormat{nhblx@hashextract}{%
  \xifinlist{\thefield{hash}}{\nhblx@boldhashes}
    {}
    {\listxadd{\nhblx@boldhashes}{\thefield{hash}}}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\nhblx@getmethehash}
  {}
  {\printnames[nhblx@hashextract][1-999]{author}}
  {}
  {}

\newcommand*{\addboldnames}{\forcsvlist\nhblx@writenametobib}
\newcommand*{\resetboldnames}{\def\nhblx@boldhashes{}}

\newcommand*{\ifhashinboldlist}{%
  \xifinlist{\thefield{hash}}{\nhblx@boldhashes}}
\makeatother

\newcommand*{\mkboldifhashinlist}[1]{%
  \ifhashinboldlist
    {\mkbibbold{#1}}
    {#1}}

\DeclareNameWrapperFormat{boldifhashinlist}{%
  \renewcommand*{\mkbibcompletename}{\mkboldifhashinlist}%
  #1}

\DeclareNameWrapperAlias{sortname}{default}
\DeclareNameWrapperAlias{default}{boldifhashinlist}

\addboldnames{{Le Texier, Marion}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{schindlerHowFarPeople2022,
  title        = {How Far Do People Travel to Use Urban Green Space?
                  A Comparison of Three {European} Cities},
  author       = {Schindler, Mirjam and Le Texier, Marion
                  and Caruso, Geoffrey},
  date         = {2022-04-01},
  journaltitle = {Applied Geography},
  volume       = {141},
  pages        = {102673},
  doi          = {10.1016/j.apgeog.2022.102673},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{schindlerHowFarPeople2022}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Mirjam Schindler, Marion Le Texier, and Geoffrey Caruso. “How Far Do People Travel to Use Urban Green Space? A Comparison of Three European Cities”. In: Applied Geography 141 (Apr. 1, 2022), p. 102673. doi: 10.1016/j.apgeog.2022.102673.]