Author Highlighting in Footnote Citations with BibLaTeX
According to this answer, it's possible to highlight specific authors in the bibliography using the \mkbibcompletename command. This is done by annotating authors with author+an in the .bib file, and redefining \mkbibcompletename in the preamble as follows:
\renewcommand*{\mkbibcompletename}[1]{%
  \ifitemannotation{highlight}
    {\textbf{#1}}%               
    {#1}%
}

I am attempting to apply a similar technique to highlight author names in footnote citations. However, when implementing this in a minimal working example (MWE), the expected bold formatting in the footnotes is not achieved:


Here, one would try to get Jordi Folch name to appear in bold in the footnote citation.
MWE:
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc} % less space under the footnotes
\usepackage{dashrule}
\usepackage[style=verbose-inote,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}

\let\oldfootnotesize\footnotesize
\renewcommand{\footnotesize}{\fontsize{8bp}{1em}\selectfont}
\renewcommand{\cite}{\autocite} % citations in footnotes
\bibliography{bibliography}

% In bibliography.bib, those entries with "author+an" will be in bold, according to: 
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/699796/50467
\renewcommand*{\mkbibcompletename}[1]{%
  \ifitemannotation{highlight}
    {\textbf{#1}}%               
    {#1}%
}


\begin{document}

Some text here \cite{Chengteh} and some other text here \cite{Folch}

\end{document}

bibliography.bib file:
@article{Chengteh,
  author = {Lee, Chengteh and Yang, Weitao and Parr, Robert G.},
  journal = {Phys. Rev. B},
  volume = {37},
  issue = {2},
  pages = {785--789},
  year = {1988}
}

@article{Folch,
  author={Folch, Jordi and Lees, Mark and Stanley, GH Sloane},
  author+an = {1=highlight},
  journal={Journal of biological chemistry},
  volume={226},
  number={1},
  pages={497--509},
  year={1957},
}


You have to add the appropriate stuff to the .bib entries for this to work, I think. There are other answers there if you don't want to do that.

The MWE is using the legacy BibTeX backend (backend=bibtex,). Data annotations are only supported with Biber and not with BibTeX. So you will have to switch to backend=biber, and will have to run Biber instead of BibTeX (see Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations for help with your editor).
Compiled with Biber the following MWE works as expected.
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[style=verbose-inote,backend=biber]{biblatex}

% In bibliography.bib, those entries with "author+an" will be in bold, according to: 
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/699796/50467
\renewcommand*{\mkbibcompletename}[1]{%
  \ifitemannotation{highlight}
    {\textbf{#1}}%               
    {#1}%
}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Chengteh,
  author = {Lee, Chengteh and Yang, Weitao and Parr, Robert G.},
  journal = {Phys. Rev. B},
  volume = {37},
  issue = {2},
  pages = {785--789},
  year = {1988}
}
@article{Folch,
  author={Folch, Jordi and Lees, Mark and Stanley, GH Sloane},
  author+an = {1=highlight},
  journal={Journal of biological chemistry},
  volume={226},
  number={1},
  pages={497--509},
  year={1957},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

Some text here \autocite{Chengteh} and some other text here \autocite{Folch}

\printbibliography
\end{document}



Many thanks for your detailed explanation
